# Can't pack buttons vertically in GTK

Tags: python, gtk

I want to pack the two buttons vertically in the box, why doesn't it work?
Here is my code.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")
        self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)
        self.button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Hello")
        self.box.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)
        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
        self.box.pack_start(self.button2, True, True, 0)


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You create `self.box`, a box with vertical orientation, then immediately overwrite it with another, completely different, new box with spacing 6 (and the default horizontal orientation). Instead do

```
self.box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
```